# Exporting third party module types

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, module

I'm writing a library in typescript which provides some abstractions for popular libraries and frameworks like express.

Does the user need to download each module's declaration files (@types/express) manually or is there a way to include them in my npm package?

Comment: What kind of "abstraction" are you talking about? If your code uses those libraries (has them as dependencies), you can import them, and of course also re-export them.

Comment: I noticed that my @types were on devDependencies rather than depencies on my package.json file. I changed them and now they export correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My question refers to how the npm pack command bundles the types so users don't need to add each @type definitions to their own package.json

I solved it by changing the @types I wanted to be packed from devDependencies to dependencies on my package.json file.

Comment: Since u add them as dependency, whoever downloads your packages, will download @types too, so I wouldn't call this as "exporting"